# Reference EnvironmentObject in ObservableObject

Tags: swiftui, combine, observableobject

I have a LoginView that shows a RegisterView if the user is not logged in, and a ContentView if he is logged in:

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userManager: UserManager
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if userManager.isRegistered {
                ContentView()
            } else {
                RegisterView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`ContentView` have three `ObservedObject` properties, that uses combine to fetch content from a server with rest api's.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userManager: UserManager
    @StateObject var usersStore = UsersStore()
    @StateObject var rolesStore = RolesStore()
    @StateObject var elementsStore = ElementsStore()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Image("stell")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .opacity(0.1)
            
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: UsersView(usersStore: usersStore) ) {
                        Text("Users")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: RolesView(rolesStore: rolesStore)) {
                        Text("Roles")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: ElementsView(elements: $elementsStore.elements)) {
                        Text("Elements")
                    }
                }.font(.title).padding(20)
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("STELL"))
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that I want to reference `userManager` from any of the observedObjects, e.g. when the rest api's returns `401 Unauthorized` when the session token has expired. Then I want the ObservedObject to set the `isRegistered` flag in `userManager` to `false` so the `RegisterView` is automatically shown. But how can I do that? I can't set a reference to `userManager` in any of the ObservedObject property initializers, because the compiler complains about property initializers is run before `self` is available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use in this case dependency injection via constructor... below is show possible approach on example of `UsersStore`, for others it would be the same

Changes in `UsersStore`

```
class UsersStore: ObservableObject {
    var manager: UserManager
    
    init(manager: UserManager) { // << inject UserManager via constructor
        self.manager = manager 
    }
    ...
}
```

Changes in `ContentView`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userManager: UserManager
    @ObservedObject var usersStore: UsersStore

    init(usersStore: UsersStore) {
        self.usersStore = usersStore // << inject UsersStore via contructor
    }
```

Changes in usage

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userManager: UserManager
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if userManager.isRegistered {
                // userManager is valid here some UsersStore can be created
                ContentView(usersStore: UsersStore(manager: self.userManager))
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't mutate any state you can do that from `body`, e.g.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userManager: UserManager
    @StateObject var usersStore = UsersStore()
    @StateObject var rolesStore = RolesStore()
    @StateObject var elementsStore = ElementsStore()

    func configureObjects(){
        usersStore.userManager = userManager
        rolesStore.userManager = userManager
        elementsStore.userManager = userManager
    }

    var body: some View {
        let _ = configureObjects()
        NavigationView {
```

And in these objects you probably want to reset things back to nil in the `didSet` of the stores (if the userManger is different object from last time) and then set things up again asynchronously or lazily when a getter is accessed from body. Also you might want to move the `@StateObject` into a custom `View` that actually accesses its properties, so you have less redundant invalidations of `ContentView`.